# In-app purchases - typical to fetch product list on every app open?

Tags: ios

I'm reading through this in-app purchase tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

In order to make a purchase, we need to do the following:

```
SKProduct* product = ...;
SKPayment* payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Looks like we need to have an instance of `SKProduct` to pass to the `addPayment:` method. Does this mean that we need to fetch the list of products our app offers from the app store every time the user opens our app?

In my case, I have a list of hard-coded product identifiers. I wonder if people fetch the list of `SKProduct` instances one time, then cache them to disk. Then a re-fetch isn't necessary until you add more products for your app. I guess dynamic attributes like the localized price would prevent caching, though.

So is it typical to re-fetch the product list every time the app runs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not mandatory to make product request each time when application launches.
It just depends on application requirement.Suppose in Your Application First Screen is Something Like The Store SCreen Where You display the Item To be sold. In that case You should   make the Product request to the Itunes Store So that You can display The Most updated Information Corresponding to Products each time when application launches.

Suppose If in your Application you display The Products List  on clicking of some Store Button(Say any Button on clicking you load Store Content). then in that case you should make the Product request at that Time and display these product on screen. And As clicking on any one of them(product) you can pass that `SKProduct` to the `SKPaymentQueue`.And In that case no need to make The Product request to the Itunes Store each time when application launches.

So here I Would Say You Firstly Need To think About Your Application requirement.
I hope It may help you.

Answer (score 1):

In my own apps, I fetch the SKProducts each time the user goes to the "store" screen within my app, not every time the app is run. If the user has no intention of buying anything at the moment, there is no need to fetch the products. Wait until the user chooses to see the details about what in-app purchases can be made in your app.

Comment: Yes I did same. But on the purchase page it's take too much time to fetch the product details. Is there any alternate solution for it?